# correlation query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, correlation

I have also seen [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-it-possible-to-calculate-a-correlation-in-a-mysql-query) which calculates the correlation between two columns. IMy question is different from that because my query is more complex, since it's not between column. I want to find the correlation between two different conditions in query.

I have a table which has data of search query history of website in it. I want to calculate the correlation of the search_no in different days. To calculate the number of search queries I have implemented the following:

```
select to_date(time), query, platform, count(query) as search_no
from search
where `_month` = 2 and time between '2021-02-05 00:00:00' and '2021-02-05 23:59:59' and platform = 'application'
group by to_date(time), query, platform
order by search_no desc limit 1000
```

[image: query result]

It works perfect. It calculates the number of searches as `search_no` for `2021-02-05`. What I want to find is the correlation between two different dates like `2021-02-05` and `2021-01-29`.

The correlation formula is as follows:

[image: correlation formula for two variables]

**PS**: x is data of the first day (`2021-02-05`) and y is the data of the second day (`2021-01-29`).

**What I have tried**

```
select (sum((x.search_no - avg(x.search_no)) * (y.search_no - avg(y.search_no))) / ((count(x.search_no) - 1) * (stddev_samp(x.search_no) * stddev_samp(y.search_no))
from (
    (
        select to_date(time), query, platform, count(query) as search_no
        from search
        where `_month` = 2 and time between '2021-02-05 00:00:00' and '2021-02-05 23:59:59' and platform = 'application'
        group by to_date(time), query, platform
        order by search_no desc limit 1000
    ) as x,
    (
        select to_date(time), query, platform, count(query) as search_no
        from search
        where `_month` = 1 and time between '2021-01-29 00:00:00' and '2021-01-29 23:59:59' and platform = 'application'
        group by to_date(time), query, platform
        order by search_no desc limit 1000
    ) as y
)
```

I don't know how can I implement it.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you just showed your data as a sample table.  It is entirely unclear what "x" is in your data, because none of the aggregating columns are numeric.  Are you sure you don't what a chi-square test?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sure, I'll add it in 3 minutes. Thank for your comment. Yeah, I just want to calculate the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the correlation of the summaries from two different days.  That would be starting with this data:

```
   select query,
         sum(date(time) = '2021-02-05') as x,
         sum(date(time) = '2021-02-06') as y,
         count(*) as cnt
  from search
  where `_month` = 2 and
         time >= '2021-02-05' and
         time < '2021-02-07' and
         platform = 'application'
  group by query;
```

You can then plug this directly into your formula:

```
with dataset as (
       select query,
             sum(date(time) = '2021-02-05') as x,
             sum(date(time) = '2021-02-06') as y,
             count(*) as cnt
      from search
      where `_month` = 2 and
             time >= '2021-02-05' and
             time < '2021-02-07' and
             platform = 'application'
      group by query
     )
select (sum( (x - avg_x) * (y - avg_y) ) /
        sqrt(nullif( sum(power(x - avg_x, 2) * power(y - avg_y, 2)), 0))
       ) as pearson_correlation
from (select d.*,
             avg(x) over () as avg_x,
             avg(y) over () as avg_y
      from dataset d
     ) d;
```

Obviously, you need to adjust the date range in the `where` clause for whatever day you want.  I see no reason to use `limit` -- that will just through the population of queries off.

Comment: I have added my own query. would you please take a look on that? I have also tried yours but it doesn't work, since I think `sum(date(time)) ` is not ok and should not be an interval.